# vb. net wait for 2nd form to close before continuing

Tags: vb.net, wait, formclosing

Is  there a way in vb.net to pause a function\ event and wait till another form has closed to contine

example:

```
    Private Sub B1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles B1.Click

label1.text="Hello testing.." '1st function

form2.show() '2nd function

'MAKE FORM WAIT FOR FORM 2 TO CLOSE...
'THEN CONTINUE WITH THE NEXT FUNCTION

msgbox("Some function that was waiting in the event") '3rd function

end sub
```

The closest I can find towards what I want is an input box but an input box is limited in what I want though it dose wait as i would like the Form2 to function.

another suggestion was to loop  untill the form2 has closed, however this is hacky and unprofesional as a solution (my oppinion)

Comment: In fact the InputBox is a modal dialog box wrapped inside a function.  If you want more functionality it's fairly simple to make your own.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just change:

```
form2.Show()
```

To:

```
form2.ShowDialog()
```

From the documentation for [ShowDialog()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog?view=netcore-3.1):

> You can use this method to display a modal dialog box in your
> application. When this method is called, the code following it is not
> executed until after the dialog box is closed

Note that in the simplified example above, we are not capturing the return value of `ShowDialog()`.

We could use the return value to determine if subsequent code should be executed or not:

```
If form2.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    ' ... do something in here ...
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ShowDialog` it Shows the form as a modal dialog box.

You can check the output result from the form using `DialogResult`

```
Public Sub ShowMyDialogBox()
    Dim testDialog As New Form2()

    ' Show testDialog as a modal dialog and determine if DialogResult = OK.
    If testDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        ' Read the contents of testDialog's TextBox.
        txtResult.Text = testDialog.TextBox1.Text
    Else
        txtResult.Text = "Cancelled"
    End If
    testDialog.Dispose()
End Sub 'ShowMyDialogBox
```

To assign the DialogResult to a button just use the button property: `button.DialogResult`

Answer (score 0):

```
public cerrar

Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

form2.show()

Do
cerrar = form2.Visible
Loop Until cerrar = False

continue codigo

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to your answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Modal forms.  Look it up and the answer will become clear.